# Make =:= commutative?

Tags: scala, type-systems

It just makes sense that `=:=` should be commutative: `A =:= B` implies `B =:= A`. I was wondering if there is a way to make the scala understand this. To elaborate, if I provide the scala with

```
implicit def typeEqCommutes[A,B](ev: A=:=B): B=:=A = ev.asInstanceOf[B=:=A]
```

then is there a way so [the following would compile:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30700212/369489)

```
    class Pair[T, S](var first: T, var second: S) {
    def swap(implicit ev: T =:= S) {
      val temp = first
      first = second //error: type mismatch; found: S required: T

      second = temp
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may not exactly be what you are asking for, but you could try being a bit more explicitly implicit:

```
class Pair[T, S](var first: T, var second: S) {
  def swap(implicit ev: T =:= S, commutative: S =:= T) {
    val temp = first
    first = commutative(second)

    second = ev(temp)
  }
}
```

finding evidence for `S =:= T` should not be a problem for the compiler as type sameness as proven by `=:=` should indeed be commutative.

If you want to do it with an implicit conversion you would have to do it like that:

```
implicit def commutativity[A, B](in: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B): A = {
  in.asInstanceOf[A]
}

class Pair[T, S](var first: T, var second: S) {
  def swap(implicit ev: T =:= S) {
    val temp = first
    first = second

    second = ev(temp)
  }
}
```

Though, imho, not needing to use `asInstanceOf` is always preferable.